# MongoDB - query references 2 deep of ObjectIDs

Tags: mongodb

I've inherited a Azure Cosmos database with a MongoDB API. There is extensive use of "discriminators" so a single collection has many different models.

I am trying to query a document three levels deep based on document ids (ObjectId())

**Parent Group**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  __type: "ParentGroup",
  name: "group 1",
  subgroups: [
    ...ObjectIds,
  ],
}
```

**Sub Group**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  __type: "SubGroup",
  name: "a text name",
  members: [
    ...ObjectIds,
  ],
}
```

**Member**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  __type: "Member",
  name: "string",
  email: "",
  induction: Date,
}
```

Examples I've seen deal with nested documents NOT references

Is it possible to query the Member documents and return?

```
[
  {
    parentGroup,
    subgroups: [
      {sub group, members: [...members]},
      {sub group, members: [...members]},
      {sub group, members: [...members]},
    ]
  },
]
```

After reading the comments and further reading i've got this. Its almost there but I think the limitation of MongoDB will prevent the solution being in a single query. The goal is to return ParentGroups->Subgroups->Members Where Members have an "induction" value of "whatever". I am either returning ALL ParentGroups or nothing at all

```
 db.development.aggregate([
     { 
         $match: { 
             __type: "ParentGroup",  $expr: {
                $gt: [
                    { $size: "$subgroups" }, 0
                    ] 
                } 
              }
    },
     {
         $lookup: {
             from: "development",
             localField: "subgroups",
             foreignField: "_id",
             as: "subgroups"
             }
     },
     {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$subgroups",
//             preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            } 
        },
         {
         $lookup: {
             from: "development",
             localField: "subgroups.members",
             foreignField: "_id",
             as: "subgroups.members"
             }
     }
 
 ])
```

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: I've updated the question with the query. I think what i am trying to do is beyond what MongoDB can do -- happy to be proved wrong

Comment: You are missing the $match stage. $lookup just converts references to embedded objects. You need to filter the result of $lookup. Are you expecting a parent group document with all members if at least one is matching, or a parent group with only matching members?  You will have better chances to get an answer if you provide an examle dataset somewhere like https://mongoplayground.net/ (the left-hand side column)

Comment: @AlexBlex, thanks for that. I had a try with filtering $lookup, but no joy

https://mongoplayground.net/p/jHMwZ2MxEpS

Comment: @user3067684, the aggregation pipeline is called pipeline after linux pipes "|" to make it easier to understand that stages executed one after other and results (output) of the first stage is the sorce data (input) for the second stage. Order matters. You need to put the $match stage at the end, when data from $lookup stages is actually available.

Comment: @AlexBlex, is there an example of this you can point me too? I think I'm having a senior moment. Thanks

Comment: @user3067684 could you be a bit more specific about "this"? It's not quite clear what examples you are asking about. Aggregation pipeline documentation is there https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#std-label-aggregation-pipeline  It describes how it works and have some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

```
db.development.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      __type: "ParentGroup",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "development",
      localField: "subgroups",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "subgroups",
    },
  },

  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$subgroups",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "development",
      localField: "subgroups.members",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "subgroups.activities_x",
    },
  },


{
    $unwind: {
      path: "$subgroups.members",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  
  {
    $match: { "subgroups.members.meta": { $exists: true } },
  },

  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      __type: 1,
      name: 1,
      subgroups: {
        _id: 1,
        __type: 1,
        name: 1,
        members: {
          _id: 1,
          __type: 1,
          name: 1,
          meta: 1,
        },
      },
    },
  },
]);
```